# Constantly receive java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception, rmiregistry

I am very new to Java and the RMI system. I am following a tutorial but I am unsure why I keep getting the following errors[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeYTn.png
I have attached the code (taken directly from the tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html)

I have tried:

- removing any lines with 'package'
- changing classpath variables
- reinstalling java and javac
- setting classpath in the 'rmiregistry &' command

Any help would be appreciated

edit: forgot to attach the code.
Hello.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    private Client() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject((Remote) obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial states that you should start the server by running this command `java -classpath classDir example.hello.Server &` but it looks like you've omitted the `example.hello.` part.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work and I was instructed by my lecturer to remove the package stuff, hence removing the example.hello. piece. It didn't work in either case. However I have found a solution by accident and ill post it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command rmiregistry & in the folder the code is compiled into. In this case, "files"

the "getting started" tutorial didn't mention that.

Comment: Or tell it that as its CLASSPATH. Or use the codebase feature.